# How to wait until an animation is finished in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nstimer

I try to let a button "shake" before the next question of my quiz is going to load.

The animation looks like

```
var timer = NSTimer()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
        self.IMGVIEWcat.center = CGPointMake(self.IMGVIEWcat.center.x + 2, self.IMGVIEWcat.center.y)
    })
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.IMGVIEWcat.center = CGPointMake(self.IMGVIEWcat.center.x - 4, self.IMGVIEWcat.center.y)
    })
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.IMGVIEWcat.center = CGPointMake(self.IMGVIEWcat.center.x + 2, self.IMGVIEWcat.center.y)
    })
```

After this the following function is called

```
    func QueryInformations(){
        println("QueryInformationsStart")
        self.ActivityIndicator.hidden = false
        ObjectIDsArrayCount = ObjectIDsArray.count
        var RandomQuestion = Int(arc4random_uniform(ObjectIDsArray.count + 0))
        var QuestionID:String = ObjectIDsArray[RandomQuestion]
        var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "AddonQuiz")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(QuestionID){
            (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
...
```

Now the animation starts but instant the next question is loaded, is there some easy wait for a beginner to implement a "waiting" until the animation is done?

I tried to set

```
var complet == true
```

In the animation

And in the query function

```
if complet = true {....
```

But this did not work for me, also I found some information about completion handler but didn't get it work in my code.

Comment: `if complet = true {...}` is not what you want to use. Use `if complet == true {...}` instead. By the way you should just use the `completion` block at the end of the animation.

Comment: true ;) in code it was == but its still did not help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use the `completion` block at the end of the animation, you should use constructs with the `delay` and `options` arguments as well.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { 
// put here the code you would like to animate
    self.IMGVIEWcat.center = CGPointMake(self.IMGVIEWcat.center.x + 2, self.IMGVIEWcat.center.y)

}, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
// the code you put here will be compiled once the animation finishes
    QueryInformations() 
})
```

Comment: getting a error on "}, completion: {" 'Bool' is not a Subtype of '()'

Comment: Glad you got it working! it's really important you understand the `options: nil` block. Instead of `nil` you could use `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear` or `UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut`. These settings modify how the animation behaves. If you use the last one the animation will begin quickly and the it will slow down as the animation completes.

Comment: What you mean by UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear or UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70661/discussion-between-fabian-boulegue-and-cecexx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `completion` block on that function you're calling:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.IMGVIEWcat.center = CGPointMake(self.IMGVIEWcat.center.x + 2, self.IMGVIEWcat.center.y)
}, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
  QueryInformations()
})
```

Comment: This currently gives me a error, "missing argument for delay"

Comment: It shouldn't. Taken straight from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion: